# Identity Framework Database First in MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

What I am trying to do:

I am trying to set up identity. It is database first where we set up the table for the ApplicationUser called "User" in the database. This table (User) has the same fields as the one build from the identity scaffolding.

What do I need to do in order to have people login via identity from the table in my database (not in the localdb)

When I change the connection string

```
public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("Myconnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
```

It gives me an error:

> The entity type ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the
>   current context.

I do not have a table called ApplicationUser.

Comment: Does the `ApplicationDbContext` implement `IdenityDbContext` or `DbContext`?

Comment: it implements IdenityDbContext

Comment: Do you use the `UserManager` or the `ApplicationDbContext` to create users? For ASP.NET Identity you need to use the `UserManager`